# form_comment_form_alter modify comment body

Tags: 7, comments, forms

I am using `hook_form_comment_form_alter` to add values to the textboxes in the commenting form. But in the comment body I can seem to add a default value
and can't seem to find a value that I can change. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
function mytheme_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm(get_defined_vars());
  $form['author']['name']['#title'] = "";
  $form['author']['name']['#default_value'] = "Name";
  $form['author']['name']['#title'] = "";
  $form['author']['mail']['#default_value'] = "Email";
  $form['author']['mail']['#title'] = "";
  $form['author']['homepage']['#default_value'] = "Website";
  $form['author']['homepage']['#title'] = "";
  $form['author']['subject']['#default_value'] = "Subject";
  //$form['comment_body']['need default value']= 'I need to add a value';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add default value to your comment form body use the following snippet,

```
 $form['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#default_value'] = "Your default value";
```

Comment: I think you should use *LANGUAGE_NONE* constant instead of directly using 'und'

Comment: @mathan you re right, i edited my answer